# Google Play - How to add yearly subscription plan to exsiting monthly subscription plan

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

Ever since [Google Play Billing Library 5](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) is introduced, a concept of `based plan` is introduced in Subscription.

A single subscription, can have multiple based plan. The based plan can be either charging monthly, or charging yearly.

Currently, we already have a legacy monthly subscription plan.

If we want to support yearly subscription plan, here is what we need to do.

[image]

1. "Add base plan" in existing subscription plan.
2. Use [ProductDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails) to perform subscription.

---

However, our legacy code haven't adopted `ProductDetails`. We are still using legacy [SkuDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails)

I was wondering, is it OK for us to

[image]

1. Add a completely new subscription plan for the yearly plan.
2. Continue to use legacy `SkuDetails` to perform subscription.

Is there any shortcoming, or pitfall for doing so?

Thanks.